# Converting date formats from one class to another

Tags: r, date

I have the following dates.

```
c("Aug 08, 2017", "Aug 09, 2017", "Aug 11, 2017", "Aug 11, 2017", 
"Aug 10, 2017", "Sep 22, 2017", "Aug 11, 2017", "Aug 11, 2017", 
"Aug 11, 2017", "Aug 14, 2017", "Aug 16, 2017", "Aug 16, 2017", 
"Aug 18, 2017", "Aug 18, 2017", "Aug 18, 2017", "Sep 20, 2017", 
"Aug 22, 2017", "Sep 20, 2017", "Sep 14, 2017", "Sep 25, 2017"
)
```

I am trying to convert them into the following format:

```
structure(c(17386, 17387, 17388, 17389, 17392, 17393, 17394, 
17395, 17396, 17399, 17400, 17401, 17402, 17403, 17406, 17407, 
17408, 17409, 17410, 17414), class = "Date")
```

Which looks like;

```
 [1] "2017-08-08" "2017-08-09" "2017-08-10" "2017-08-11" "2017-08-14" "2017-08-15" "2017-08-16" "2017-08-17"
 [9] "2017-08-18" "2017-08-21" "2017-08-22" "2017-08-23" "2017-08-24" "2017-08-25" "2017-08-28" "2017-08-29"
[17] "2017-08-30" "2017-08-31" "2017-09-01" "2017-09-05"
```

How can I convert characters to date format?

EDIT:

I run the following;

```
> C=c("Aug 08, 2017", "Aug 09, 2017", "Aug 11, 2017", "Aug 11, 2017", 
+     "Aug 10, 2017", "Sep 22, 2017", "Aug 11, 2017", "Aug 11, 2017", 
+     "Aug 11, 2017", "Aug 14, 2017", "Aug 16, 2017", "Aug 16, 2017", 
+     "Aug 18, 2017", "Aug 18, 2017", "Aug 18, 2017", "Sep 20, 2017", 
+     "Aug 22, 2017", "Sep 20, 2017", "Sep 14, 2017", "Sep 25, 2017"
+ )
> as.numeric(as.Date(C,format='%B %d, %Y'))
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
> as.Date(C,format='%B %d, %Y')
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

EDIT:
The following also does not work;

```
date <- gsub(",", "", date)
date <- gsub(" ", "-", date)
date

as.numeric(as.Date(date, format='%b %d, %Y'))
```

EDIT:

The following seems to work;

`mdy(C)`

Giving;

```
[1] "2017-08-08" "2017-08-09" "2017-08-11" "2017-08-11" "2017-08-10" "2017-09-22" "2017-08-11" "2017-08-11"
 [9] "2017-08-11" "2017-08-14" "2017-08-16" "2017-08-16" "2017-08-18" "2017-08-18" "2017-08-18" "2017-09-20"
[17] "2017-08-22" "2017-09-20" "2017-09-14" "2017-09-25"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need using the `format` in `as.Date`

```
as.numeric(as.Date(C,format='%B %d, %Y'))
 [1] 17386 17387 17389 17389 17388 17431 17389 17389 17389 17392 17394 17394 17396 17396 17396 17429 17400 17429 17423 17434

as.Date(C,format='%B %d, %Y')
 [1] "2017-08-08" "2017-08-09" "2017-08-11" "2017-08-11" "2017-08-10" "2017-09-22" "2017-08-11" "2017-08-11" "2017-08-11" "2017-08-14" "2017-08-16"
[12] "2017-08-16" "2017-08-18" "2017-08-18" "2017-08-18" "2017-09-20" "2017-08-22" "2017-09-20" "2017-09-14" "2017-09-25"
```

Dinput:

```
C=c("Aug 08, 2017", "Aug 09, 2017", "Aug 11, 2017", "Aug 11, 2017", 
"Aug 10, 2017", "Sep 22, 2017", "Aug 11, 2017", "Aug 11, 2017", 
"Aug 11, 2017", "Aug 14, 2017", "Aug 16, 2017", "Aug 16, 2017", 
"Aug 18, 2017", "Aug 18, 2017", "Aug 18, 2017", "Sep 20, 2017", 
"Aug 22, 2017", "Sep 20, 2017", "Sep 14, 2017", "Sep 25, 2017"
)
```

Comment: This returns NA values

Comment: @user113156 check with your sample , and run with it again , I think it should be work ,also my C is your input vector

Comment: I am still running into errors. I think its to do with the `as.numeric` part (I have edited the original post so you can see what I have done)

Comment: `chr [1:183] "Aug 08, 2017" "Aug 09, 2017" "Aug 11, 2017" "Aug 11, 2017" "Aug 10, 2017" "Sep 22, 2017"`

Comment: I just tried your code on a different laptop & Rstudio and still get NA´s

Comment: Okay this seems to solve the problem from the `lubridate` package `mdy(C)` - not sure why other methods were not working